# Least velocity of projection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

If the range is given, then why does the least velocity of projection occur when the angle of projection is $45°$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For horizontal projection:

$$R=\frac{u^2\sin2\theta}{g}$$

Obviously, for a given $R$, $$u^2=\frac{Rg}{\sin2\theta}$$

Hence, $u^2$ is minimum when $\sin2\theta$ is maximum.